# iOS: how to restrict localization?

Tags: ios, localization

Brief:

I have a project with support of several languages (.strings files).
But now I want to remove one locale OR restrict user to change locale.

Issue:
How to leave only one locale?

I have several localization.strings files:

Main.strings
Authorization.strings
Settings.strings

And for each of these files I need to remove every locale except my desirable locale?
Too bruteforce. Maybe there is an elegant solution?

Comment: You can't remove localisation files at runtime, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @Abizern ok, but can I hide them or disable in xcode without removing?

Comment: What would be the point of that?

Comment: @Abizern I have a project like `core engine` and I need to leave only one localization (my business partner want this feature)